# Reverse for 'create_song' not found. 'create_song' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, reverse

I have a Django project in which the page that should load to show the album that has just been added, does not. It should go to the primary key for that album (auto generated) with the reference: http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/ but instead gives the error:

**Reverse for 'create_song' not found. 'create_song' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

A variant of the same problem, I assume, Is that when I click on the VIEW DETAILS BUTTON (shown below in the index.html) it doesn't load:

```
 <div class="caption">
                            <h2>{{ album.album_title }}</h2>
                            <h4>{{ album.artist }}</h4>

                            <!-- View Details -->
                            <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">View Details</a>

                            <!-- Delete Album -->
                            <form action="#" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id }}" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
```

The code for the various sections is below:

**music/templates/music/album_form.html**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'music/form_template.html' %} <!-- how form fields and inputs are laid out-->
                        <div class="form-group>
                            <div class="col-sum-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

**music/views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Album

#=============HOME PAGE===================
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    #specify template being used
    template_name='music/index.html' #when we get a list of all albums, plug them into this template
    context_object_name='all_albums' #if you don't use this variable it is automatically just object_list (which is used in index.html)

    #make a query set
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


#=============DETAILS VIEW=============== details about one object
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    #what model are we looking at /for
    model=Album
    template_name='music/detail.html'

#===============For the add album form  
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']
```

**music/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views #the dot means look at the current directory - look for a module called views

app_name='music'

urlpatterns = [
    #this is matching /music/
     path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
     #when you use a detail view it expects a primary key
     path("<pk>/", views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
     #/music/album/add - dont need to specify pk
     path('album/add/', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name="album-add"),
]
```

music/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Album(models.Model):
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo=models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.album_title+""+self.artist

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
        #music detail takes the primary key ..


class Song(models.Model):
    album=models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

**Update: also including details.py**

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ album }}{% endblock %}
{% block albums_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid songs-container">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Left Album Info -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">
                        {% if album.album_logo %}
                            <img src="{{ album.album_logo.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                        {% else %}
                            <h3>No image to display</h3>
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                    <h1>{{ album.album_title }} <small>{{ album.genre }}</small></h1>
                    <h2>{{ album.artist }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Song Info -->
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">View All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'music:create_song' album.id %}">Add New Song</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <h3>All Songs</h3>

                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Audio File</th>
                            <th>Favorite</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ song.song_title }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="{{ song.audio_file.url }}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>&nbsp; Play
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{% url 'music:favorite' song.id %}" class="btn-favorite"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star {% if song.is_favorite %}active{% endif %}"></span></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{% url 'music:delete_song' album.id song.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <input type="hidden" name="song_id" value="{{ song.id }}" />
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp; Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue, but you're missing a double quote:
```<div class="form-group>``` should be ```<div class="form-group">```

Comment: Thanks, have changed that now, but it doesn't resolve the *main* issue :)

Comment: You talk about an error then you put code don't raise this error.

Comment: Oops - thanks, have also included the models.py - I think the error either lies there or in the index.html.Obviously, if I knew I wouldn't be asking the question!

Comment: You have code in your template, view or model which is trying to reverse `create_song`, but you haven’t included that in your question. The problem might be in `music/detail.html`. You haven’t shown the URL pattern with `name='create_song'` either.

Comment: Thanks - have included details.py in the question. What is reverse 'create_song'.....actually doing? I've included the code for where I thought that was happening in models.py. I don't fully understand what create_song is at all, and where it should be (as I never coded it in anywhere) so don't understand where the error is coming from!

Comment: you have this line `url 'music:create_song'` in the navbar for right song info.

Comment: @Jason ...are you saying I need to include that line in my urls.py???

Comment: you would need to make a url with that name parameter, and have it call a create view